# Vb.net - Only show context menu strip if item is clicked

Tags: vb.net

I've got a listview full of items. And I've added a contextmenustrip to that listview. Now, I want the menustrip to only appear if an item in the listview is selected. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ContextMenuStrip class has the event [Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.onopening.aspx) that could be handled to check the presence or not of [selected items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx) on the ListView.
This event receives an CancelEventArgs parameter where you can find the Cancel property and set it to True to cancel the opening if the condition required happens.

```
Private Sub ContextMenuStrip1_Opening(sender As System.Object, e As CancelEventArgs) _ 
        Handles ContextMenuStrip1.Opening
        If Me.listView1.SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
End Sub
```